# Firebase grouping of auto generated ID tags

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hello & thanks in advance, using swift 4- After retrieving my Firebase data, i am trying to group everything by Auto generated child ID- the (LKQvTZIe...) parts. My reason for doing this is because the "image, planit, title" all represent one complete post. I need to display the links in a collection view that is tied with the "title" and "planit" parts of the post, so each auto generated ID needs to be tied together.

**My question** - Is there any way to group or call things by those Auto generated ID's?

That seems like a logical way for me to assure that all 3 of these nodes are grouped together.   [image]

THIS IS THE VIEW DID LOAD SECTION

```
let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        ref = Database.database().reference()





    //ref.child("planits").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    ref.child("planits").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in


        let FirebaseDataDict = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]

        print(FirebaseDataDict)
        // THIS GRABS THE EXACT USERS PLANIT DETAILS FROM THE DATA BASE
        for child in snapshot.children { //.value can return more than 1 match
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let dict = snap.value as? NSDictionary


            let senderID = dict!["senderId"]

            // IF USER ID EQUALS THE SENDER ID IN DATABASE, THEN UPLOAD THEIR PLANITS
            if userID == senderID as! String {


            let titleOfPlanit = dict!["title"] as! [String]


            let imagesForThisPlanit = dict!["images"] as! [String]

            let individualPlanName = dict!["plans"] as! [String]

                imagesInPlanit = imagesForThisPlanit

                self.nameOfSinglePlan = individualPlanName

                self.nameOfThisPlanit.append(contentsOf: titleOfPlanit)




            }
        }

    })
```

// JSON RESPONSE, FOR INSTANCE - THE FIRST 3 BLOCKS OF CODE BELONG TO A SINGLE PLANIT, THE NEXT 3 BELONG TO THEIR OWN SEPERATE PLANIT

```
["marketing party "]
["https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F34047334%2F203533422144%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=234%2C0%2C734%2C367&s=26d86a54d46bcbe86ee2a2728f0b89b4", "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F42440910%2F68964867283%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=0%2C318%2C4592%2C2296&s=3aa7bf43a9a2c647e92a6aa5d11ce1bc"]
["Digital Marketing Training in Pomona,CA-USA|Eduscil", "SoulfulofNoise The Tour @ Pomona"]
["send "]
["https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.com%2Fimages%2F45161425%2F210370190852%2F1%2Foriginal.jpg?h=200&w=450&auto=compress&rect=0%2C4%2C1920%2C960&s=b575da96cc7c5b13b36ba82e666e693a"]
["RRB Dance Company Parivaar Night"]
```

Comment: If you are talking about `grouping` so that you don't have to subscript always to find the values, then you need to create model objects from them.

Comment: @nayem I’d like to group it so that I can funnel them into a table view and collection view accordingly

Comment: I noticed your code commented "if the user id equals the sender id, then do something" - a description of an authorization workflow. Could you use Firebase realtime database rules and move all that logic up to the server?

Comment: @ericl i am actually not to sure about that. This is my first time dealing with a Firebase backend so i'm iffy on a few things. Are you asking me if its possible or implying that i should implement that ?

Comment: @nayem your solution was the correct way for the issue i needed to achieve. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any experience in Swift but here's what you should do with Firebase about collecting posts:
When you request a child or child, you can ask for a uid for this posts
Now you can order the parts very normally
If you understand in Android or Java, the calls are as :

```
ref.child("planits").child(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid).
ref.child("planits").child(senderid).
```

You can not post any value with the same name
FireBase creates random names for each new child
If you intend to create a child with the same name in a child, I find that is not possible
You can assemble the rest of the parts in order by `Query`

Comment: Thank you for your response. By uid - do you mean just the users id? As in receiving only the posts that specific user made?

Comment: Order, you can assemble them by senderid

Comment: Yes i understand what you are saying, i am able to filter by sender ID. the sender ID is equal to the userID. The thing is, say a user has more than 1 post. I get back multiple chunks of code that come back in separate blocks (they're not attached by those LKEI3.. numbers up there anymore - I will update question to show you a response i get). So now, i have no way to intemperate which images or title belongs to which group of post. Because i am attaching each complete post to table view, so they need to remain in a group. if you understand

Comment: Do You Know Androids?
I can spell it out in Java and convert it to Swift Switcher
Is this useful?

Comment: I know a bit of android. And yes I can use swift switcher to transfer if you send it. Very useful. I appreciate it

Comment: I have found a solution already. No need too. Thank you though